# How to convert IV on openssl_encrypt to string?

Tags: php, encryption

I have this code to encrypt a string.

```
$textToEncrypt = "some text to encrypt";
$secretHash = "some-hash";
$encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC"; 

$ivlen1 = openssl_cipher_iv_length($encryptionMethod);
$iv1 = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen1);
$encryptedMessage1 = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash, 0, $iv1);
```

And I am able to encrypt and decrypt it using the secret hash and the iv. My question is, the iv is on bytes. How can I convert it to string so that the "decryptor" knows what it is and able to decrypt.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function "openssl_random_pseudo_bytes" generates a pseudo-random string of bytes. You could create your own method of generating a random string to use as your IV.

However, if you specifically want to make this binary data visible as a string that isn't random garbage, you could pass it through the "bin2hex" function.

```
echo $iv1 . "\n"; //outputs something like: "��I݂6B{�M [r"
$stored = bin2hex($iv1);
echo $stored . "\n"; //outputs something like: "8cbc49dd82361508427be5954d0d5b72"
```

This gives you a usable string which if you want the original binary data, you can just pass that string back through the function "hex2bin".

```
echo hex2bin($stored);  //again something like: "��I݂6B{�M [r"
```